# Dynamic assembly selection and loading in runtime

Tags: .net, reflection, appdomain

I have an application that has reference to **Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.dll** assembly (part of **SQLXML**). But on different machines, depending on whether it's live environment or test, or developers local PC, different versions of **SQLXML** are installed. This arises an issue: depending on destination machine I have to compile application against correct **Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.dll** assembly.

In Subversion I keep csproj and dll file that is used on live environment. When I have to test modules that take advantage of **Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.dll** locally, I change reference in project, and revert them back. But several times I forgot to rollback changes and I checked in csproj and **Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.dll** with version that didn't comply with **SQLXML** installed on live server. As a result, I received runtime errors.

My question is: is there any way to dynamically load assemblies in runtime? I can have switch statement somewhere in application that would load correct assembly depending on entry in app.config (eg. env="live|test|local") ? Or perhaps there is another way to address this issue?

Thanks,Pawel

Comment: Ensure that Specific Version is set to false on your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908/en-us):

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);

private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender,ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    //This handler is called only when the common language runtime tries to bind to the assembly and fails.

    //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
    Assembly MyAssembly,objExecutingAssemblies;
    string strTempAssmbPath="";

    objExecutingAssemblies=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    AssemblyName [] arrReferencedAssmbNames=objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

    //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
    foreach(AssemblyName strAssmbName in arrReferencedAssmbNames)
    {
        //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
        if(strAssmbName.FullName.Substring(0, strAssmbName.FullName.IndexOf(","))==args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")))
        {
            //Build the path of the assembly from where it has to be loaded.                
            strTempAssmbPath="C:\\Myassemblies\\"+args.Name.Substring(0,args.Name.IndexOf(","))+".dll";
            break;
        }

    }
    //Load the assembly from the specified path.                    
    MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);                   

    //Return the loaded assembly.
    return MyAssembly;          
}
```

Naturally you have to change the part `//Build the path of the assembly` using what you need.

Comment: Thanks ! One more question though: I still have reference in csproj set to particular version of DLL: <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlXml, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">. If I load assembly in version 3.0 in live env, will it work?

Comment: @dragonfly: do what Guillaume told you: "Ensure that Specific Version is set to false on your reference"